# C read line as string

Tags: c

```
char *word[128];
fgets(word, 128, stdin);
if(word == "hello")
    printf("You entered hello as your word.");
```

So basically I am trying to get user input as a string and then use the following comparison so see if the string the user entered is equal to "hello". however, when compiling this code, it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: So based on feedback so far this is what I have:

```
char word[128];
fgets(word, 128, stdin);
if(strcmp(word, "Hello") == 0)
     printf("match\n");
```

However, when I compile and run this program and enter Hello it does not print "match".

Comment: `==` is not how string comparisons are done in C. Use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: If you learn how to *hard-code* and *print* strings, you can separate the two functions (getting user input and comparing strings) and tackle them independently.

Comment: Is me needing to use strcmp the only thing that is wrong with the above code? Is the string defined properly and would fgets work in this case with how the string is defined?

Comment: `char *word[128]` should be `char word[128]`. That plus `strcmp` should work.

Comment: C does not have a string type. It is all convention.

Comment: Kaylum could you please look at the edit I did to the question

Comment: Try `if(strcmp(word, "Hello\n") == 0)`

Comment: Always read carefully the man pages for the functions you use. From the [`fgets` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer." That is, `word` contains a newline character and hence it is not a match.

Comment: Ooo okay got ya thanks adding \n in the comparison fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)` to compare strings.
Also change `char *word`to `char word[]`.

`fgets`, as you used it, reads in characters from `stdin` until it has read **new line**, **127** characters or **EOF** (end of file). **The new line is part of the string read in `word`** and so the comparison is not equal.

To illustrate, you need to know that a C-style string is an array of characters ended by the special escape character `\0`. So you are comparing those two strings `hello\n\0` and `hello\0`; note the newline character in the string read from `stdin`.

You can overwrite the `\n` at the 6th position with `\0` so your strings compare to equal.
A better, general solution is to simply iterate over the characters of the string and replace the first found `\n` by `\0`; this could be a good exercise for you maybe.

`==` does not compare the strings the way you expect it. It merely compares the addresses of the two objects, which in this case are of course different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strcmp to compare strings.

```
if(strcmp(word, "Hello") == 0)
  printf("match\n");
```